# CakePhp 3 elastic search

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have installed the elastic search based on the documentation
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/elasticsearch.html

I am getting an error "Unknown repository type "Elastic". Make sure you register a type before trying to use it." 
by adding   $this->loadModel('test', 'Elastic');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you have the Elasticsearch plugin installed via Composer.
And then load the plugin by adding a line in `config/bootstrap.php`.

```
Plugin::load('Cake/ElasticSearch', ['bootstrap' => true]);
```

*If you have Composer installed globally, run:

```
composer require cakephp/elastic-search "@stable"
```

in your application root directory. Hope this will help!